# Exibir imagem somente nos que possuem dados no banco e exibir nome ao passar o mouse na imagem

Tags: php, html, css

Boa tarde, eu tenho uma listagem de pacientes, aonde exibe arquivos através de um `href` dando para visualizá-los, **eu quero que exiba uma imagem invés de um "link"** (como está na foto abaixo) **e quando eu passar o mouse acima da imagem, apareça o nome do arquivo.** Porém somente nos dados que possuem arquivos cadastrados...

Não sei o que fazer, acho que deve-se usar `IF` e `ELSE`...

> **Meus campos da tabela:** educacao_fisica, enfermagem, nutricao, pedagogia, terapia_ocupacional, servicos_sociais.

**PROBLEMA**: A imagem aparece em todos os campos, mesmo sem ter arquivos nesse X campo.

[image: PRINT]

**Código da página (listagem_relatorio.php):**

```
<?php

require('conexaobd.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM relatorio";

$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$inc = 0;



while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

    echo "
        <tr>


                <td>".$cont['paciente']."</td>  

                <td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsed/".$cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica']."' target='_blank'>".$cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica']."<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/zhoolego/material/512/Filetype-Docs-icon.png' style='width:30px; height:30px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>


                 <td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsenf/".$cont['relatorio_enfermagem']."' target='_blank'>".$cont['relatorio_enfermagem']."</a></td>

                     <td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsnut/".$cont['relatorio_nutricao']."' target='_blank'>".$cont['relatorio_nutricao']."</a></td>

                      <td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsped/".$cont['relatorio_pedagogia']."' target='_blank'>".$cont['relatorio_pedagogia']."</a></td>

                         <td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadster/".$cont['relatorio_terapia_ocupacional']."' target='_blank'>".$cont['relatorio_terapia_ocupacional']."</a></td>

                         <td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadser/".$cont['relatorio_servicos_sociais']."' target='_blank'>".$cont['relatorio_servicos_sociais']."</a></td>

        </tr>
    ";
}

?>
```

*Alguém tem alguma ideia? Grato.*

Comment: Caso não exista arquivo, o que retorna nessa variável `$cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica']` ?

Comment: Não retorna nada, fica em branco

Comment: E quando não tem arquivo, o que irá ser mostrado?

Comment: Nada também '-', Exemplo: https://prnt.sc/qu4q5y

Comment: Ficando algo desse tipo ? https://prntscr.com/qu4was

Comment: Isso, ai quando passar o mouse por cima de um arquivo, exibir o nome daquele arquivo, entendeu?

Comment: https://prntscr.com/qu4xw8, vê se é isso

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103810/discussion-between-samuel-verissimo-and-pedro-henrique).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de criar a coluna, realize uma verificação se a informação do banco existe algum arquivo.

Para simplificar foi usada a operador ternária para realizar a verificação.

```
<?php
echo "
<tr>
    <td>{$cont['paciente']}</td>";

echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'] != "" ? "<td><a style='color: Blue' href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsed/{$cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica']}' title='{$cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica']}' target='_blank'><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/zhoolego/material/512/Filetype-Docs-icon.png' style='width:30px; height:30px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>" : "<td></td>";

/**
 * Adicionar o restando das colunas, relatorio_enfermagem, relatorio_nutricao, ....
 * Lembrando de trocar a pasta também
 */

echo "</tr>";
?>
```